# Questions before writing own RSS reader for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, rss, xmlreader, google-reader

This is not new topic, one about iPhone ( [iPhone RSS Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682033/iphone-rss-reader-parsexml-wont-load-some-xml-feeds) )

My purpose is to get some latest and useful info before my implementation for RSS reader in iPad.( same with iPhone , right ? only GUI difference ?)

Apple already provides [TopSongs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TopSongs/Introduction/Intro.html) as example, which use native NSNetwork and XML parser etc.

ASIHttpRequest also provides good features to download RSS xml data and use cocoa-rss to parse it. Just like [Reading RSS Feeds on iPhone/iPad with ASIHttpRequest and cocoa-rss](http://www.building43.com/blogs/2010/05/28/reading-rss-feeds-on-iphoneipad-with-asihttprequest-and-cocoa-rss/)

Search in github with rss, there are a lot projects around it.

So my questions may be like these:

- 1). what is the best or popular open source projects for RSS reader for iPhone&iPad now ?
- 2). The workflow can be simplified as network connection --> download --> parse xml --> display data,  any real issues around this ?
- 3). GoogleReader is just one common RSS reader example ? I mean, common rss reader also can be used to read google rss reader contents ?

Thanks for any other comments or suggest to help me learn more around this.

Answer (score 1):

While not a complete answer for all of your questions, hopefully this will help out with your second question. I found this article by one of the devs of NetNewsWire to be very insightful on some of the challenges that will come up when making your own reader, especially one that will need to sync across multiple devices):

[Why “Just Store the App Data on Dropbox” won’t work for RSS readers](http://inessential.com/2011/10/25/why_just_store_the_app_data_on_dropbo)